# How can i pass a state to the file app.js in react?

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react, i have this code which i got from my manager, i have to add an event, actually on button click i have to add a class to other component, the button is in Header component, and the class i have to add is in LeftNav.
Here is my header.js

```
export class Header extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
      anchorEl: null,
      gettingUser: false,
      loggingOut: false,
      menuOpen: false
    };
    this.cookies = new Cookies();
  }
```

i made a state menuOpen.
and tried setting state to true like this in header.js

```
<Button className="menu-btn-wrapper header-button" onClick={() => self.setState({ menuOpen: true })}>
            <i className="icon circle zf-cs-icon-burger"></i>
          </Button>
```

and moving on to my app.js, i have this

```
<Header history={history} />
<LeftNav className="leftFixed leftNav" />
```

How can i get the state of menuOpen from Header here?
i tried

```
<Header history={history} menuOpen={this.state.menuOpen} />
```

but i am getting a stateless error.
There is no class present in app.js
Here is my full app.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { compose } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import IdleTimer from 'react-idle-timer';
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';

import { LinearProgress, IconButton, Tooltip } from '@material-ui/core';
import { Cancel as CancelIcon } from '@material-ui/icons';

import { getToken, updateMaxAge, expirySet } from '../auth';
import { cancelFileUpload, setSnackbar } from '../actions/appActions';
import { logoutUser, saveUserSettings, setAccountActivationCode, setShowConnectingDialog } from '../actions/userActions';
import { privateRoutes, publicRoutes } from '../config/routes';
import { onboardingSteps } from '../constants/onboardingConstants';
import SharedSnackbar from '../components/common/sharedsnackbar';
import ErrorBoundary from '../errorboundary';
import { getOnboardingState } from '../selectors';
import { colors } from '../themes/mender-theme';
import Tracking from '../tracking';
import { getOnboardingComponentFor } from '../utils/onboardingmanager';
import LiveChatBox from './livechatbox';
import ConfirmDismissHelptips from './common/dialogs/confirmdismisshelptips';
import DeviceConnectionDialog from './common/dialogs/deviceconnectiondialog';
import Header from './header/header';
import LeftNav from './leftnav';
import 'react-perfect-scrollbar/dist/css/styles.css';
import PerfectScrollbar from 'react-perfect-scrollbar';

const activationPath = '/activate';
const timeout = 900000; // 15 minutes idle time
const cookies = new Cookies();

export const AppRoot = ({
  cancelFileUpload,
  currentUser,
  history,
  logoutUser,
  onboardingState,
  setAccountActivationCode,
  setShowConnectingDialog,
  showDeviceConnectionDialog,
  showDismissHelptipsDialog,
  setSnackbar,
  snackbar,
  trackingCode,
  uploadProgress
}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (trackingCode) {
      if (!cookies.get('_ga')) {
        Tracking.cookieconsent().then(({ trackingConsentGiven }) => {
          if (trackingConsentGiven) {
            Tracking.initialize(trackingCode);
            Tracking.pageview();
          }
        });
      } else {
        Tracking.initialize(trackingCode);
      }
    }
    history.listen(trackLocationChange);
    trackLocationChange(history.location);
  }, []);

  const trackLocationChange = location => {
    // if we're on page whose path might contain sensitive device/ group/ deployment names etc. we sanitize the sent information before submission
    let page = location.pathname || '';
    if (page.includes('=') && (page.startsWith('/devices') || page.startsWith('/deployments'))) {
      const splitter = page.lastIndexOf('/');
      const filters = page.slice(splitter + 1);
      const keyOnlyFilters = filters.split('&').reduce((accu, item) => `${accu}:${item.split('=')[0]}&`, ''); // assume the keys to filter by are not as revealing as the values things are filtered by
      page = `${page.substring(0, splitter)}?${keyOnlyFilters.substring(0, keyOnlyFilters.length - 1)}`; // cut off the last & of the reduced filters string
    } else if (page.startsWith(activationPath)) {
      setAccountActivationCode(page.substring(activationPath.length + 1));
      history.replace('/settings/my-profile');
    }
    Tracking.pageview(page);
  };

  const onIdle = () => {
    if (expirySet() && currentUser) {
      // logout user and warn
      return logoutUser('Your session has expired. You have been automatically logged out due to inactivity.').catch(() => updateMaxAge());
    }
  };

  const onboardingComponent = getOnboardingComponentFor(onboardingSteps.ARTIFACT_CREATION_DIALOG, onboardingState);
  const containerProps = getToken() ? { id: 'app' } : { className: 'flexbox centered', style: { minHeight: '100vh' } };
  return (
    <div {...containerProps}>
      {getToken() ? (
        <>
          <IdleTimer element={document} onAction={updateMaxAge} onIdle={onIdle} timeout={timeout} />
          <Header history={history} />
          <LeftNav className="leftFixed leftNav" />

          <PerfectScrollbar className="rightFluid container main">
            <ErrorBoundary>{privateRoutes}</ErrorBoundary>
          </PerfectScrollbar>

          {onboardingComponent ? onboardingComponent : null}
          {showDismissHelptipsDialog && <ConfirmDismissHelptips />}
          {showDeviceConnectionDialog && <DeviceConnectionDialog onCancel={() => setShowConnectingDialog(false)} />}
          {
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
            ENV === 'production' && <LiveChatBox />
          }
        </>
      ) : (
        publicRoutes
      )}
      <SharedSnackbar snackbar={snackbar} setSnackbar={setSnackbar} />
      {Boolean(uploadProgress) && (
        <div id="progressBarContainer">
          <p className="align-center">Upload in progress ({Math.round(uploadProgress)}%)</p>
          <LinearProgress variant="determinate" style={{ backgroundColor: colors.grey, gridColumn: 1, margin: '15px 0' }} value={uploadProgress} />
          <Tooltip title="Abort" placement="top">
            <IconButton onClick={cancelFileUpload}>
              <CancelIcon />
            </IconButton>
          </Tooltip>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

const actionCreators = { cancelFileUpload, logoutUser, saveUserSettings, setAccountActivationCode, setShowConnectingDialog, setSnackbar };

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    currentUser: state.users.currentUser,
    onboardingState: getOnboardingState(state),
    showDismissHelptipsDialog: !state.onboarding.complete && state.onboarding.showTipsDialog,
    showDeviceConnectionDialog: state.users.showConnectDeviceDialog,
    snackbar: state.app.snackbar,
    trackingCode: state.app.trackerCode,
    uploadProgress: state.app.uploadProgress
  };
};

export default compose(withRouter, connect(mapStateToProps, actionCreators))(AppRoot);
```

and in main.js

```
export const Main = () =>
  render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <ErrorBoundary>
          <Router basename="/ui/#">
            <App />
          </Router>
        </ErrorBoundary>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('main') || document.createElement('div')
  );
Main();
```

Comment: you cannot directly read/mutate state between different components.  You should wrap your components inside a  parent component, then in the parent component declare state and a function to update the state, than pass as props to child components state and/or function. in your case pass to the header component the callback, and in the LeftNav the state variable.

Comment: oh i think i get it, i have to make a parent component around both, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root component is `AppRoot`, that is a Functional Component.

define the menuOpen state in `AppRoot` with useState:

```
const [menuOpen,setMenuOpen]=useState(false)
```

then define a function in `AppRoot` to handle menuOpen changes:

```
const  handleMenuOpen=()=>{
            setMenuOpen(true)
     }
```

then pass the handler function to the `Header` via props:

```
<Header history={history} onButtonClick={handleMenuOpen} />
```

inside the Header:

```
<Button className="menu-btn-wrapper header-button" onClick={() => this.props.onButtonClick()}>
        <i className="icon circle zf-cs-icon-burger"></i>
      </Button>
```

`AppRoot` after all above steps:

```
export const AppRoot = ({
  cancelFileUpload,
  currentUser,
  history,
  logoutUser,
  onboardingState,
  setAccountActivationCode,
  setShowConnectingDialog,
  showDeviceConnectionDialog,
  showDismissHelptipsDialog,
  setSnackbar,
  snackbar,
  trackingCode,
  uploadProgress
}) => {


const [menuOpen,setMenuOpen]=useState(false)
const  handleMenuOpen=()=>{
        setMenuOpen(true)
 }
  useEffect(() => {
    if (trackingCode) {
      if (!cookies.get('_ga')) {
        Tracking.cookieconsent().then(({ trackingConsentGiven }) => {
          if (trackingConsentGiven) {
            Tracking.initialize(trackingCode);
            Tracking.pageview();
          }
        });
      } else {
        Tracking.initialize(trackingCode);
      }
    }
    history.listen(trackLocationChange);
    trackLocationChange(history.location);
  }, []);

  const trackLocationChange = location => {
    // if we're on page whose path might contain sensitive device/ group/ deployment names etc. we sanitize the sent information before submission
    let page = location.pathname || '';
    if (page.includes('=') && (page.startsWith('/devices') || page.startsWith('/deployments'))) {
      const splitter = page.lastIndexOf('/');
      const filters = page.slice(splitter + 1);
      const keyOnlyFilters = filters.split('&').reduce((accu, item) => `${accu}:${item.split('=')[0]}&`, ''); // assume the keys to filter by are not as revealing as the values things are filtered by
      page = `${page.substring(0, splitter)}?${keyOnlyFilters.substring(0, keyOnlyFilters.length - 1)}`; // cut off the last & of the reduced filters string
    } else if (page.startsWith(activationPath)) {
      setAccountActivationCode(page.substring(activationPath.length + 1));
      history.replace('/settings/my-profile');
    }
    Tracking.pageview(page);
  };

  const onIdle = () => {
    if (expirySet() && currentUser) {
      // logout user and warn
      return logoutUser('Your session has expired. You have been automatically logged out due to inactivity.').catch(() => updateMaxAge());
    }
  };

  const onboardingComponent = 

getOnboardingComponentFor(onboardingSteps.ARTIFACT_CREATION_DIALOG, onboardingState);
      const containerProps = getToken() ? { id: 'app' } : { className: 'flexbox centered', style: { minHeight: '100vh' } };
      return (
        <div {...containerProps}>
          {getToken() ? (
            <>
              <IdleTimer element={document} onAction={updateMaxAge} onIdle={onIdle} timeout={timeout} />
<Header history={history} onButtonClick={handleMenuOpen} />
              <LeftNav className="leftFixed leftNav" />
    
              <PerfectScrollbar className="rightFluid container main">
                <ErrorBoundary>{privateRoutes}</ErrorBoundary>
              </PerfectScrollbar>
    
              {onboardingComponent ? onboardingComponent : null}
              {showDismissHelptipsDialog && <ConfirmDismissHelptips />}
              {showDeviceConnectionDialog && <DeviceConnectionDialog onCancel={() => setShowConnectingDialog(false)} />}
              {
                // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
                ENV === 'production' && <LiveChatBox />
              }
            </>
          ) : (
            publicRoutes
          )}
          <SharedSnackbar snackbar={snackbar} setSnackbar={setSnackbar} />
          {Boolean(uploadProgress) && (
            <div id="progressBarContainer">
              <p className="align-center">Upload in progress ({Math.round(uploadProgress)}%)</p>
              <LinearProgress variant="determinate" style={{ backgroundColor: colors.grey, gridColumn: 1, margin: '15px 0' }} value={uploadProgress} />
              <Tooltip title="Abort" placement="top">
                <IconButton onClick={cancelFileUpload}>
                  <CancelIcon />
                </IconButton>
              </Tooltip>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      );
    };
```

Comment: There is no class in app.js, how can i pass a constructor there?
i have edited my question and added my whole app.js file, can you please check?